# How to change value in go array?

Tags: go

Here is what I am trying todo

```
for _,p := range *players {
        for _,tp := range *tournamentPlayers{
            if p.Id==tp.PlayerId {
                p.Points += tp.Prize

            }
        }
    }
```

after for nothing is saved

Comment: In most cases there is little value, if any, of having pointers to slices (e.g. `*[]Player`). You should instead use slices of pointers to type xyz (e.g. `[]*Player`). If you do that your code would work. And of course nothing stops you from doing this `*[]*Player` which would also make your code work, but don't do it if you don't have to.

Comment: Thank for the idea with *[]*Player. I did not need to mess with copies and rewrite a lot of code

Answer (score 4):

When you `range` over an array, the second variable will be a copy of the value. So when you're modifying it, you don't actually modify the value stored in the array.

You need to use the index:

```
for i := range *players {
        for _,tp := range *tournamentPlayers{
            if players[i].Id==tp.PlayerId {
                players[i].Points += tp.Prize

            }
        }
    }
```

You'll find more informations in the [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#RangeClause).